# In which direction is the microphone signal transported?

Tags: audio, microphone, electromagnetic, balanced, unbalanced

So I understand the general principle of how the audio signal is transported. I also understand that audio signals can be distinguish between AC and DC.
But let's say we have a TRRS Jack like below. I will use the names in the pictures to explain.

I understand the signal for the headphones in "DC" case in theory is going through the "Left" (+ pole) and "Right" (+ pole) because "Ground" (- pole) works as ground. But now I don't understand how it works with the microphone. If the "Microphone" is (+ pole) and "Ground" is still (- pole), where is the signal transported to? Is the microphone signal transported into "Ground" (- pole)? Or the "Microphone" (+ pole), but the current does not flow in that direction.
So in principle my question is how does the signal reach the end-stage?

Edit:
The thing is, when we're listening to music, we put the TRRS in the plug and a signal is then sent to "Right" and "Left", it gets into the headphones and the music plays - "Ground" serves as a negative pole, only as a reference for these two "Right" and "Left" signals to determine which direction they need to flow in. Well now we have the "Microphone" as (+pole) and Ground as (-pole). But the microphone, as a device In other words, it doesn't send the signal into the "microphone" (+pole) because that's not the direction of the current. So the signal might be sent into the "ground" (-pole) and picked up by the end device (e.g. computer, mobile phone ) on the "ground" (-pole).. I don't think so. So how does this work correctly?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Audio signals don't have intelligence; they can't distinguish anything.

Comment: edited, but common, just help to answer the question instead of playing a wise guy

Comment: Good engineering is about sifting through the details to extract meaning or advantage. In other words being a "wise guy" comes with the territory.

Comment: We've  just moved from audio signal to who's the better engineer. Yes, you are the better one, but please could we now focus on my question, and help me? Thank you

Comment: What are the T, R and S poles you talk about? Wouldn't it be better to refer to the names in the image or, adjust the image to suit the names you use?

Comment: Please, see the edit

Comment: OK, sorry to say, after all of that, I got the the bottom of your question and I don't understand what you mean by "transport". The microphone signal is present on the microphone pole and the ground pole and, where it gets transported to is where the jack plugs into.

Comment: I can't really understand what is the question. In a phone, Left and Right are Ground referenced signal outputs and Mic is a Ground referenced input. Can you be more specific what the confusion or question is?

Comment: please, see my edit. And thank for the down vote, very helpful

Comment: Your question suggests that you use another way of thought or different vocabulary for it, compared to EE standards. I suggest,  take a step back, ask simple incremental questions to learn the common language, because otherwise you and answerers will never understand each other.

Comment: You only have fixed + and - poles for DC. With an AC signal they are constantly swapping over.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question to me. I can tell that the asker has some confusion, but the only way to get the confusion resolved is to ask questions. It certainly wouldn't be reasonable for us to ask someone to _first_ resolve all their confusion surrounding a subject and _then_ ask questions about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a lot of misconceptions about how electric signals work.

It sounds like you're thinking that a signal has to travel in the same direction as the current. That's not true; the direction of the current and the direction that the signal goes are actually unrelated.

It also sounds like you're thinking that the Left, Right, and Mic wires are always at a positive voltage relative to Ground. That's not true either; the Left and Right wires are positive about half of the time and negative about half of the time. (However, you're right about the Mic wire; that one is always positive, because it's also used to supply power to the microphone.)

So how does it actually work?

Audio signals are voltage signals, and a voltage is always defined as the difference between two conductors. So, the Left signal is transmitted using the difference between the Left wire and the Ground wire; the Right signal is transmitted using the difference between the Right wire and the Ground wire; and the Mic signal, the difference between the Mic wire and the Ground wire.

We usually imagine that the Ground wire carries no information and merely acts as a reference for the other wires. Technically, if we wanted to, it would be equally valid for us to imagine that, say, the *Left* wire carries no information, and the Right and *Ground* wires carry the stereo audio signal. But that would be a really confusing way of thinking about things. Instead of doing that, we choose to do things the easy way: we choose to think of the Ground wire as the reference.

So, that leaves us with three wires that carry information: Left, Right, and Mic. From now on, I'm going to write "the voltage of the Left wire" when what I really mean is "the voltage of the Left wire relative to ground."

So, imagine that you plug a headset into a laptop. How do the signals get transmitted between the two devices?

Well, the laptop has components in it that allow it to change the voltage on the Left wire and the voltage on the Right wire. So the laptop changes those voltages very rapidly, making them higher (more positive) when the audio signal is higher and lower (more negative) when the audio signal is lower. The headset has components in it that allow it to detect what the voltages on the Left and Right wires are. So the headset looks at those voltages and produces a sound corresponding to the way that those voltages are changing.

That's how the laptop sends signals to the headset using the Left, Right, and Ground wires.

Also, the headset has components in it that allow it to change the voltage on the Mic wire, and the laptop has components in it that allow it to see what the voltage on the Mic wire is. So the headset does the same thing the laptop did: it moves the voltage on the Mic wire up and down according to the incoming sound. Then the laptop looks at the way the voltage is changing, and converts that information into a digital signal that the software on the laptop can use.

That's how the headset sends a signal to the laptop using the Mic and Ground wires.

The Mic wire is a bit of a weird case, because it carries power from the laptop to the microphone *and* it carries a signal from the microphone to the laptop. Basically, what happens is that the laptop is always pulling the voltage up, but, if I understand correctly, it pulls it up with a certain amount of "gentleness" (impedance), and then the microphone is able to send a signal by controlling the exact voltage.

Comment: @Tanner-reinstateLGBTpeople A niggle here: "all three wires are positive about half of the time and negative about half of the time.", nope, untrue.  The microphone wire is positive all of the time.  This is called "plugin power".  It creates a current through the FET in the microphone capsule, and the amount of that current changes with the sound pressure on the mic membrane (and consequently the voltage on the FET's gate).  That current changes strength but never direction.

Comment: @user107063 I've never heard that called "plugin power". I've always heard "phantom power".

Comment: @user107063 Ah, I didn't know that! Thanks for the correction. I'll try to fix that part of my answer if I find the time. Now I'm wondering if the signal back from the microphone is generally a voltage signal or a current signal; do you know that offhand?

Comment: @Hearth Not everything you hear is the same.  Phantom power is typically 48V through 6.81kOhm on both signal wires of a balanced signal, plugin power is something like 3V through 2.2kOhm (but with a whole lot of variation from about 1.2V to 9V) on the signal wire of an unbalanced signal.  The former is used on XLR connectors, the latter on 3.5mm TRS (stereo for video mics), minidot, mini-XLR/TQG and some other wireless mic connectors.  There are active adapters for converting phantom power (typical on mixers) to plugin power (typical for wireless and some instrument mics).

Answer (score 4):

An attempt to clear up a misunderstanding - hope it doesn't cause more confusion...

> But now I don't understand how it works with the microphone. If the
> "Microphone" is (+ pole) and "Ground" is still (- pole), where is the
> signal transported to? Is the microphone signal transported into
> "Ground" (- pole)? Or the "Microphone" (+ pole), but the current does
> not flow in that direction.

Perhaps a misunderstanding is that current flows *always* in loops - complete loops - from a source. In this system, there are **three** sources: two are at one end of the cable (right & left voltage sources V2, V1) while the third is at the other end of the cable (microphone MIC1). Sources at opposite ends seems to be causing confusion.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmyu9l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With three sources, the common ground line carries three currents, all mingling together and adding/subtracting linearly. The three "hot lines" (microphone, left, right) carry individual currents so that unlike ground, no mingling...the right earphone hot-line only carries current for the right earphone.

Current direction is shown at a particular moment - be aware that direction changes with time, since voltage waveform from each source generates **alternating currents**.

The fact that the common ground carries three currents *can be a problem* if this wire resistance is too high - in this case, it is possible that the microphone amplifier might see some of the left and right signals. You might see a robust, thick ground wire in an effort to reduce its resistance so that co-mingling signal currents generate very little voltage along its length.

Comment: An electret microphone is not a source of power.  It is a varying power _sink_.  All energy flows in the same direction (right to left in your diagram), but the microphone provides a varying resistance to what is called "plugin power", and the consequently differing current is sensed.

Comment: @user107063 OP's question seems AC related. Yes, electrets are DC-biased - and what you say is true - an added complication that would likely cause further confusion. The provided schematic does not show electret bias loop but is still valid for AC signals. I have deleted a paragraph about power to avoid DC/AC confusion.